# Show fixed div after specific point (responsive)

Tags: jquery

I have a div with fixed buttons in it. I also have a page with a form on it, and i want to hide the fixed div until i reach the send button (bottom) of my form.

I have been experimenting with this (could be a bit crappy):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#MyFixedDiv").hide(); //hide your div initially
  var topOfOthDiv = $("#MyForm").offset().top;
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() > topOfOthDiv) { //scrolled past the other div?
        $("#MyFixedDiv").show(200); //reached the desired point -- show div
    } else {
        $("#MyFixedDiv").hide(200); //reached the desired point -- hide div
    }
  });
});
```

The problem of this is that .offset().top isn't showing my fixed div after the send button. For window resizes not the best solution.

The best way until now was to play with z-index, but i think there might be a more elegant solution.

Is there a way to show my fixed div always when the user has reached the absolute bottom of my form where the send button is, even if the screen is 320px width or 1280px width? Like an anchor point for -tags.

EDIT: Here is an example:

[image]

Between the top of the screen and the bottom of my form it has to be invisible, whatever height it may take, then underneath my form it has to appear and stay fixed all the way to the bottom.

Comment: Do you have a live link we could take a look at?

Comment: No sorry, i've hoped my explanation was enough.

Comment: a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) would help, with your CSS and HTML

Answer (score 0):

In [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lv86ph8k/3/), I show a working example.

Ideally, it is best to do something like this with CSS as much as possible. The element is fixed and hidden to begin with, then a class that makes it visible is added once you reach a certain scroll point. This class is then removed if you scroll too high again (and so on and so forth).

I am not 100% sure what caused your bug of it not displaying. It may have been the initial `$("#MyFixedDiv").hide();`. Once I started using CSS to show/hide, I didn't encounter it again.

Comment: Yes i understand, but i want it to be visible from a certain point, so i cant give it a height to scroll from. I has to have an anchor point to scroll from, so it will start from that point and not from a height ,cause my form is responsive like the rest of it. Ive added an image to hopefully make it a little more clear for you.